# how to avoid overlapping on submit?

Tags: javascript, visualforce

[image]

Here is my code :

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="False" id="pge">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{!URLFOR($Resource.web2caseResources,'web2case/css/validationEngine.jquery_Dacia.css')}" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8" />
<!-- MaskValidation -->
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.MaskFuntion}"/> 
<!---ValidationPlugin---->
<script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.web2caseResources,'web2case/js/jquery_min.js')}" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.web2caseResources,'web2case/js/jquery.validationEngine-es.js')}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.web2caseResources,'web2case/js/jquery.validationEngine.js')}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.web2caseResources,'web2case/js/Rforce_ESWebtoCase.js')}" type="text/javascript"></script> 

<style>
form{
   width:540px;
   background-color:#EDEDED;
   font-family: Arial,"Trebuchet ms",Verdana,sans-serif;
   font-size: 11px;
   font-family: Arial,"Trebuchet ms",Verdana,sans-serif;
   padding: 7px 7px 0px 7px;
}
div #button{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 3px;
}
input.text {
    border: 1px solid #DADCDE;
    color: #484848;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 16px;
    padding-top: 4px;
}
p{
    font-family: Arial,"Trebuchet ms",Verdana,sans-serif;
    color: #A2A5A4; 
    font-size: o.70em; 
}
h2{
    line-height: 1.5px;
    font-family: Arial,"Trebuchet ms",Verdana,sans-serif;
}

#CPF_Web__c,#email,#Phone,#Fname1,#Lname1,#description,#VIN_Web__c,#License_Number_Web__c,#Address,#CEP,#Complemento,#Cidade,#Estado,#ContactMobile{
    width: 410px;
}
#Numero{
    width: 150px;
}
#Endereço{
    width: 410px;
}
#left {
   float: left;
}
#right {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}
div #backbutton{
    float: right;
}
</style>  
</head>  

<form id="formID"  > 
    <Label >Si quiere realizar una consulta, una reclamación o hacer una sugerencia, cumplimente por favor el formulario a continuación.Para poder gestionar su petición, necesitamos por favor algunos datos personales.
    </Label>
<br></br><hr color = "white"></hr>        
        <br></br>

     <label for="Title_Web__c"> Tratamiento</label><br/>
        <select  id="Title_Web__c">
            <option value="Mr.">Sr.</option>
            <option value="Mrs.">Sra.</option>
            <option value="Miss.">Sta.</option>
        </select><br/>
        <hr color="white"></hr>


<Label for="Lname" >APELLIDO 1*</Label>      
 <br></br> 
<input id="Lname" class="validate[required,length[2,20]] text-input " maxlength="20" size="20" type="text" style="width:500px" />
<br></br>

<span>       
<Label for="Fname" >NOMBRE*</Label>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
<Label for="Surname" >APELLIDO 2*</Label>
<br></br>
<input id="Fname" class="validate[required,length[2,20]] text-input" maxlength="30" size="20" type="text" style="width:250px" /> 
&nbsp;
<input id="Surname" class="validate[required,length[2,20]] text-input" maxlength="20" size="20" type="text" style="width:235px" />
</span>

  <hr color="white"></hr>

  <Label for="email" >E-mail*</Label><br></br>
   <input id="email" maxlength="80" size="48" class="validate[required,custom[email]]" style="width:500px" />

    <hr color = "white"></hr>

                    <Label for="phone" >Teléfono fijo</Label><br></br>
                    <input id="phone" maxlength="10" name="phone" size="48" style="width:500px" />
                    <hr color = "white"></hr>

                    <Label for="Mobile">Teléfono móvil*</Label><br></br>
                    <input id="ContactMobile" class="validate[required,custom[telephone]]" maxlength="10" size="48"   style="width:500px" />
                    <hr color = "white"></hr>
<span>       
<Label for="Dnumber" >Nº</Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;     
<Label for="Street" >Calle</Label>
<br></br>
<input id="number" maxlength="20" size="20" type="text" style="width:250px" />
&nbsp;
<input id="Street" maxlength="20" size="20" type="text" style="width:238px" />
</span>  

<br></br>
  <hr color="white"></hr>

<span>        
<Label for="flat" >Piso</Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
<Label for="door" >Puerta</Label>
<br></br>
<input id="flat" maxlength="20" size="20" type="text" style="width:250px" />
&nbsp;
<input id="door" maxlength="20" size="20" type="text" style="width:238px" />
</span>
<br></br>
  <hr color="white"></hr>

<span>        
<Label for="city" >Ciudad</Label>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
<Label for="state" >Provincia</Label>
<br></br>
<input id="city" maxlength="20" size="20" type="text" />
&nbsp;
<input id="state" maxlength="20" size="20" type="text" />
</span>
<br></br>
  <hr color="white"></hr>
<span>       
<Label for="vin" >Chasis</Label>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; 
<Label for="regno" >Matricula</Label>
<br></br>
<input id="vinno" maxlength="17" size="20" type="text" />
&nbsp;
<input id="RegNo" maxlength="20" size="20" type="text" />
</span>  

<br></br> 
  <hr color="white"></hr>

<Label for="km">Kilómetros</Label>
<br></br>
<input id="km" type="number" /> 
 <br></br>
   <hr color="white"></hr>
               <Label for="casetype">Tipo*</Label><br></br> 
               <select  id="Type" name="casetype" >
               <option value="Information Request">Solicitud de información</option>
               <option value="Complaint">Reclamación</option>
               <option value="Service Request">Sugerencia</option>
               <option value="Other">otro</option>
               </select><br/>
               <br></br>
   <hr color="white"></hr>
   <Label for="description">Descripción*</Label><br></br>
<Textarea  id="description" class="validate[required]"  maxlength = "800" rows="8" cols="57"/>    
 <br></br>
   <hr color="white"></hr>

     <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jquery}"/>
     <script type="text/javascript"> 
         var __sfdcSessionId = '{!GETSESSIONID()}'; 
         var filesToUpload = [];   
         var uploadedFile = 0; 
     </script> 
     <style> 
       .FilebuttonStyle{       
           font-family:Arial,'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,sans-serif; 
           font-size:13px;color:#FFFFFF; 
           background-color: #169fcc !important; 
           text-decoration:none; 
           text-align:center; 
           border:1px solid #1691ba !important; 
           line-height: 25px;!important; 
           border-radius:4px; 
           display:inline-block; 
           cursor:pointer; 
           width:40px; 
       } 

     td.fileRow { 
           overflow: hidden; 
           font-family:Arial,'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,sans-serif; 
           font-size:13px;color:#ffffff; 
           background-color: #8db728; 
           text-decoration:none; 
           text-align:center; 
           border:1px solid #6c8049; 
           line-height: 32px;!important; 
           border-radius:4px; 
           //padding-left:10px; 
           //padding-right:10px; 
           background-image:linear-gradient(top,#9dcc3d,#7da223); 
           background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#9dcc3d,#7da223); 
           background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#9dcc3d,#7da223); 
           background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#9dcc3d,#7da223); 
           background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top,#9dcc3d,#7da223); 
           display:inline-block; 
           cursor:pointer; 
           width:120px; 
           overflow: hidden; 
 } 


 td.fileRow  input { 
     display: block !important; 
     width: 157px !important; 
     height: 57px !important; 
     opacity: 0 !important; 
     overflow: hidden !important; 
 } 
   .fileCheckBox { 
        width: 16px; 
     height: 16px; 
     display: inline-block; 
     margin: 3px 5px 3px 3px; 
     background-color: white; 
         //box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #b0b3ae; 
     text-align: center; 
     vertical-align: top;  
    } 

         .FilebuttonGroup{ 
          float:right; 
         padding-right: -70px!important; 
         } 
     </style>    
     <script src="/soap/ajax/32.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

     <script type="text/javascript"> 


     function uploadFile() 
         {          
         alert('Inside uploadFile');      
         var cas = new sforce.SObject("Case");

         cas.Title_Web__c = document.getElementById("Title_Web__c").value; 
         cas.FirstName_Web__c = document.getElementById("Fname").value;  
         cas.Second_name_Web__c = document.getElementById("Surname").value;
         cas.LastName_Web__c = document.getElementById("Lname").value;
         cas.SuppliedEmail = document.getElementById("email").value;
         cas.SuppliedPhone = document.getElementById("phone").value; 
         cas.Cell_Phone_Web__c = document.getElementById("ContactMobile").value;
         cas.City_Web__c = document.getElementById("city").value;
         cas.State_Web__c = document.getElementById("state").value;
         cas.License_Number_Web__c = document.getElementById("RegNo").value;
         cas.VIN_Web__c = document.getElementById("vinno").value;
         cas.Type = document.getElementById("Type").value;
         cas.Subject = document.getElementById("Type").value;
         cas.description = document.getElementById("description").value;

         cas.Language_Web__c = "Spanish";     
         cas.CaseBrand__C = "Dacia";
         cas.Priority = "Normal";
         cas.Status = "New";
         cas.Origin = "DACIA SITE";
         cas.CaseSubSource__c = "Webform";
         cas.From__c = "Customer";
         cas.RecordTypeId = "012b0000000cQKC";
         cas.CountryCase__c = "Spain";

             $("input[type=file]").each(function(){ 

               filesToUpload.push($(this)[0].files[0]); 
             }); 
         var casCreationCheck = false; 
         var fileSize = 0;  
          var attSelect = document.getElementById('fileID').value;
          alert(attSelect);
            if(attSelect !== '') {
              for(var i = 0, f; f = filesToUpload[i]; i++) 
             { 
                 var reader = new FileReader(); 

                 // Keep a reference to the File in the FileReader so it can be accessed in callbacks 
                 reader.file = f; 
               fileSize = fileSize + f.size;
               if (fileSize <=1000) {
                 alert(fileSize);
                   } 
             else 
             {
             casCreationCheck = true;
             alert('The file '+ f.name + ' is more than 25MB which is not acceptable');
             }

           }   
     if(casCreationCheck == false) {        
     for(var i = 0, f; f = filesToUpload[i]; i++) 
        {                                            
         var caseResult = sforce.connection.create([cas]);  
         var caseId = caseResult[0].id; 



                 reader.onload = function(e) 
                 { 
                     var att = new sforce.SObject("Attachment"); 
                     att.Name = this.file.name; 
                     att.ContentType = this.file.type; 
                     att.ParentId = caseId; 


                     var binary = ""; 
                     var bytes = new Uint8Array(e.target.result); 
                     var length = bytes.byteLength; 


                     for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) 
                     { 
                         binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]); 
                     } 

                     att.Body = (new sforce.Base64Binary(binary)).toString(); 


                     sforce.connection.create([att], 
                     { 
                         onSuccess : function(result, source) 
                         { 
                             if (result[0].getBoolean("success")) 
                             { 
                                 console.log("new attachment created with id " + result[0].id); 
                             }

                            else 
                             { 
                                 console.log("failed to create attachment " + result[0]); 
                             } 
                         }, 

                         onFailure : function(error, source) 
                         { 
                             console.log("an error has occurred " + error); 
                         } 
                     });

                 };   
                     reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f); 

                      } 
                      } 
                   }
                   else {
                   var a = sforce.connection.create([cas]);
                   var b = a[0].id;
                   alert(b);
                   }  

             }                     


       function addRow(tableID){                 

          var row = '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" onclick="processCheckbox()" name="chk" class="fileCheckBox"/</td><td class="fileRows"><input type="file" onchange="createuploadAttachment(this)" </td></tr>'; 
        $('#'+tableID).append(row);   

       } 

     function deleteRow(tableID) 
     {     
         try 
         { 
             var table=document.getElementById(tableID); 
             var rowCount=table.rows.length; 
             for(var i=0;i<rowCount;i++) 
             { 
                 var row=table.rows[i]; 
                 var chkbox=row.cells[0].childNodes[0]; 
                 if(null!=chkbox&&true==chkbox.checked) 
                 { 
                     table.deleteRow(i); 

                    filesToUpload.splice(i, 1); 
                    // console.log(filesToUpload); 
                    rowCount--; 
                    i--; 
                } 
             } 
            processCheckbox(); 
          } 
          catch(e) 
          { 
             alert(e); 
          } 
      } 

     function processCheckbox(){ 
            $("[id$='_remove']").hide(); 
          var checkCount=0; 
             $("#dataTable input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){ 
             if($(this).is(':checked')) 
             { 
                 checkCount++; 
             } 
            }); 
           if(checkCount >0){ 
                $("[id$='_remove']").show(); 
           } 

         } 
   </script> 
       <div class="FilebuttonGroup"> 
         <input type="button" value="-" id="_remove" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')"  class="FilebuttonStyle" title="Delete Row"/> 

         <input type="button" value="+" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" id="_add"   class="FilebuttonStyle" title="Add Row"/> 
        </div>    
         <table id="dataTable"  >       
             <tbody> 
                 <tr> 
                     <td> </td> 
                     <td class="fileRows"> <input type="file" id = "fileID" class="fileInput" onchange="createuploadAttachment(this);"/> </td> 
                     <td></td> 
                 </tr> 
             </tbody>        
        </table> 
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar"/>

     <div id="statusid"></div>      
    <script> 
         $(document).ready(function(){ 
              $("[id$='_remove']").hide(); 
            $("[id$='attachmentBlock']").find('.pbSubsection').attr({'style':'margin-right:-70px !important;'}); 
          }); 

    </script> 

             </form>
  </apex:page>
```

In the Rforce_ESWebtoCase , the validationcomplete function is there to validate the null value validation. In that function , I call another function called "uploadFile".When I submit the page , the whole form validation is done but the page gets overlapped like below..
 Please provide me the solution.. Thanks in advance !!

Comment: You really might want to consider reformatting this and trying to be a bit clearer on what you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are having a refresh on the page without a redirect. So the page is getting refreshed and fetch the html components in development mode and shows that along with the already available html components in development mode.

Its nothing to do with your Visualforce page. If you just disable Development Mode in your user page you won't be seeing this odd behaviour.

One thing to note is, the html is not rendered twice, only the development mode footer will get rendered twice.

Hope it helps.